# Adding External JARs to Openshift

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar, openshift

I have a pretty basic Java web application (created using Eclipse openshift plugin). The app runs fine on the OpenShift server. Now I need to use an external JAR library for JSON parsing and creation in Java. I can't understand my way around how to add that JAR to openshift server.

I went to *project properties>>BuildPath>>Add external JAR*. While that does import the JAR, it does not work on openshift server and gives error relating to that file's import (`NoClassDefFound`, I guess). Could you tell me how to import external jars into openshift project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we use Maven for the build process, all you have to do is add it as a dependency in your pom.xml

Here is an example that adds a mongo driver

https://github.com/thesteve0/openshift-mongo-spatial-jee6/blob/master/pom.xml

Look under the dependencies tag

Answer (score 1):

You can add the jar as a dependency in your pom.xml file. This will cause the jar to be included in your war. If the jar is not available in a public maven repo, please see here: http://www.billdecoste.net/?p=16

Answer (score -1):

[Updates in 2017]
You might want to take a look at this [link](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/dependencies.html) from OpenShift itself.
It includes information about adding jars with and without maven dependencies.